# Casting different datatypes to char? in c

Tags: c, casting

I have a bunch of different datatypes I want to pass to char but when I do the usual format for passing ints:

```
    char number=(char)one;
```

It only works for integers. With other datatypes it gives me the numerical vales when I want the string representation. What is the easiest way to do this?
P.S. please explain answer thoroughly because I also have pointer size problems as well when I try to cast it this way. Only c syntax please
Thank you

Comment: Please list some examples. A `char` is an integral datatype, so I guess I'm not sure what you want?

Comment: A `char` is a character, which (as adamdunson said) is an integer. It's not a string, so I'm not sure what you mean by "string representation".

Comment: What you want to do is not "cast", you want to format.

Comment: "I want the string representation".  This is not a cast, use sprintf like others have said.  A piece of advice, 99% of the time you do not want to cast.  If you have to cast, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the string representation of the datatypes, I think what you want is the [sprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) function. For example, for a float type you would do:

```
float example = 3.6;
char temp[64]; // Allocate a string of size 64.
sprintf(temp, "%f", example);
```

This will store a string representation of `example` in temp.

Comment: is there anyway to do this without printing it?

Comment: There are other ways, but you don't want to use them, at least not for floating-point types. `sprintf()` doesn't print anything on the screen or printer, if you're concerned about that.

Comment: its still returning the number value even though I cast it and what about datatypes like uid_t or struct utsname

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is an integer type, which means it can be converted to and from integers(less than `256`).

> With other datatypes it gives me the numerical vales when I want the
>   string representation.

technically, a string is not a `char`. It is a `char` array, and hence, will decay into a pointer eventually.

For each of your types, you will have to create your own `toString()` sort of function(s), and return formatted strings accordingly.

Easiest way: use `sprintf()`

Answer (score 0):

Let's go over this one line, one word at a time, to get the concepts correct.

```
char number=(char)one;
```

- The first `char` is a declaration, it means I'm creating a variable of type `char`.  `char` is a 1-byte (8-bit) data type, which is usually used to hold single characters, but fundamentally it's a byte; as such it can hold values from 0x00 (a.k.a 0) through 0xFF (a.k.a 255).
- `number` is the name of a variable of type `char`
- `=` is the assignment operator; you are going to set the value of `number`
- `(char)` means "whatever the type of the variable that's is after me, interpret it as a `char`".  This is called "casting to `char`".  (*NOT* "passing to char").
- From your code, I can't tell what `one` is.  But if it's anything except a `char` or a integer number between 0 through 255, the assignment does not make sense.

The summary is that `number` is just a char, which will hold a one-byte value, and if you assign something else to it, you'll probably get undesirable results.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation the above code was just an example. one was just suppose to be any int variable. It was just suppose to show how was trying to cast. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you are after something like this:

```
char number = '0' + one;
```

This will work for one = [0, 9]